# library imagemagick deosn't work with image at path

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have installed imagemagick, and I'm testing this library with the sample code.

If the image is located in the same directory than the php script, it works. But if I put it in a folder, it doesnt:

```
$imagick = new Imagick('./img/image.jpg');
```

My script returns an error code 500.

For example:

```
<?php

 $imagePath = "/img/image.jpg";

function thumbnailImage($imagePath)
{
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $imagick->setbackgroundcolor('rgb(64, 64, 64)');
    $imagick->thumbnailImage(100, 100, true, true);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
thumbnailImage();
```

Comment: Sorry for pure enlish =(

Comment: Did you try an absolute path?

Comment: Hmmm.. That filepath `$imagePath = "/img/image.jpg";` doesn't look right. That would be an absolute filepath from the root of the filesystem. Where is the image really located?

Comment: Also, you call `thumbnailImage();` with no parameter. Inside the function, `$imagePath` will be empty.

Comment: Path looks wrong. Try with `$imagePath = __DIR__ . "/img/image.jpg";`, assuming the img folder lies with the code. And **please**, provide whatever error you see in your php log.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/c3ae240e3481f33a898d0b32fa356ba3 Sorry, but absolute path not work =(

Comment: yivi -Thanks, it's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an absolute path, when you should be using a relative path.

When you say:

```
$imagePath = "/img/image.jpg";
```

You are saying that the image is located in a folder `img` at the root of of your filesystem.

Assuming that the img folder lies in the same folder than your code, e.g.:

```
-- code_folder/
  -- script.php
  -- img/
    -- image.jpg
```

You need to provide a relative path.

You can use the `__DIR__` predefined constant, which always point to the same folder where the your script is, and concatenate the folder/image path.

E.g.:

```
$imagePath = __DIR__ . "/img/image.jpg";
```

Also, you are defining `thumbnailImage();` with one parameter, are setting `$imagePath`, but are NOT passing that parameter. Not good.

So you should do:

```
thumbnailImage($imagePath);
```

That should work.

Next time, try to look at your php error log to find more information about what is going on. A 500 error is too general and doesn't help at all to troubleshoot.